# git branching with different users

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm kinda new to git so maybe my question will not make sense. If you have better git usage suggestions, this may well be what I'm looking for.

My situation is as follow : there are 3 users and now 2 repositories.

- OldTeam is user1
- ProjectOwner is user2
- Me is user3.

OldTeam is the admin for the origin repository.
ProjectOwner has read / write access to origin repository.
Me doesn't have access anywhere.

I used `ProjectOwner` credentials to checkout the `OldTeam`'s repository. Then I somehow branched it to `Me`'s repository and made modifications there, using the local copy.

Now I want to push my changes to `OldTeam` from `Me` but still don't have write access to their repo. When I use `ProjectOwner` credentials, TortoiseGit and SourceTree (I'm using a bitbucket account) don't seem to let me merge the 2 of them. `git log` show common ancestry, but I can't get around the fact that they are now based in separate accounts.

I'm now planning on creating a patch from work in `Me`'s repo and apply this to `OldTeam`'s origin, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: What error do you get when you push?

I would think that you should eventually have your own credentials to push to the master repo instead of borrowing ProjectOwner's. Also, when you say "Then I somehow branched it to Me's repository" I think what you mean is that you cloned from ProjectOwner's repo to your own?

Comment: I don't really get any error message, but when I use ProjectOwner to push, I can only push to Me repo. I think that what happened is that I clone OldTeam locally with ProjectOwner credentials then branched that with Me.

Comment: You should probably look at the [forking workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow/), or at a minimum one of the other four workflows.  With a team of a dozen developers and two dozen main repositories (not counting the developer's forks), we use the forking workflow to good effect in Github.